# Spring callbacks I can handle

Tags: java, spring

In Spring docummentation mentioned many lifecycle steps: both for container and bean (see pictures below). But when I started to look for annotations (interfaces to implement) I couldn't find anything except of:

1. @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy callacks
2. Custom BeanPostProcessor implementation
3. Custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor implementation

If I correctly understand those pictures, I can use:

- `BPP` calback of `Container lifecycle` via custom realization of `BeanPostProcessor`.
- `init-method` and  `destroy` calbacks from `bean lifecycle`.

***Questions:***

If I can use only 3 callbacks of container and bean lifecycle.. ***What is the information below for?*** I mean why I should know all those lifecycle steps if I can't profit from them. ***May be I forgot some callbacks that I can use?***

Container lifecycle:
[image]

Bean lyfecycle:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed all the `*Aware` intefaces, which are mentioned in the diagram (mainly from `org.springframework.beans.factory` package):

- BeanNameAware
- BeanFactoryAware
- ApplicationContextAware
- InitializingBean
- DisposableBean

Whenever your bean implements one of those interfaces, Spring will call their methods at corresponding lifecycle step.

Comment: Hah, thanks. Can you disclose practical situations in which someone may whant ot use each of those interfaces please?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk those interfaces were more often used in the past when the annotations (`@Autowire`, `@PostConstruct`, `@PreDestroy`, etc) didn't exist yet. For instance, `InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet()` is very similar to `@PostConstruct`. Both can be used to check if the state of the bean is correct after initialization. Have a look at documentation of those interfaces, they give some hints and examples describing their purpose.